# Full page horizontal sliding with regular vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, css, horizontal-scrolling

I was looking into [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) to create full page, horizontal sliding content. My issue is that some of my content needs vertical scrolling within a slide. Fullpage doesn't really support this, and I guess it's not really made for it. I was wondering what the best way to achieve this would be.

```
|--- header ----|    |--- header --|
| page 1        |    | second page |
| more  content |    |             |
| ...           |    | this one is |
| ...           |  > | shorter     |
| ...           |    |             |
| ...           |    |             |
|-100% height---|    |--- footer --|
| needs to      |
| scroll to see |
|--- footer  ---|
```

Hopefully this example makes sense. The first page would have a regular vertical scrollbar and controls (or arrow keys) would allow to slide to the second page. What's possible with fullpage is to use [slimscroll](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll) to add a scrollbar to the overflow and keep each page the same height (100%) and although that works, I'd much rather have a natural scrollbar.

Any ideas on how this could be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try and integrate a bit of flexbox in it.
Not sure what fullpage provides but the code below should help you set it up nicely.

[see my pen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVgrvr)

using

```
display: flex;
align-items: stretch;
```

on the container, and I'm flexing the body and footer elements within that too, so that the footer sticks to the bottom.

Also note the

```
height: 100vh;
```

on the body and main container element.

I hope it helps.